# Is it possible to send DTO list using Retrofit2 in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I'm a student studying Android programming using Kotlin. I'm currently working on a small project.
I need to send a DTO list so that the server side can use it as follows.

```
dataList[0].text    // data type: string
dataList[0].file    // data type: file
```

I found a way to send a list of files and a way to send a list of non-file data. But I couldn't find a way to send a list of objects with a set of file and non-file data.
How do I write a Retrofit service definition to send a list of that type of object?
The content type when sending is multipart/form-data.

Here's how I tried and failed.

```
@Multipart
@POST("/post")
fun addPost(
    @Part dataList: List<DataItem>  // It didn't work.
): Call<PostResponse>
```